# Rails validation fails even when data is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Here is the command that I'm executing in Rails Console:

```
Person.create!(:firstName=>"matt", :lastName=>"master", :gender => 1)
```

My result is this error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Firstname can't be blank
```

My model validation code looks as such:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'fk_ssmUserId'
validates_presence_of :firstName, :lastName
```

When I comment out `validates_presence_of` everything works and my data is entered properly into the database, so I know that the values are actually being passed into the new object.  I even inspected the new object created inside the Rails::ActiveRecord::Validations code to make sure it was being instantiated correctly before being saved.  It was.  Also, I have other models with validates_presence_of that work 100% fine every time.  It's just this one model.  I am using Rails 3.1.0.rc1.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
:firstName=>"matt", :lastName=>"master", :gender => 1
```

check that the key correspond to your model columns. Seems to be everything should be fine.

Comment: The key definitely corresponds to the model columns.  That's why the object instantiates properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that this error relates to the fact that you're creating and saving the object using the **.create!** method ***from the console***. Your **Person** class appears to require a foreign key, a value which is probably not being instantiated when you create an object at the console. To test this, try typing:

```
test = Person.create(:firstName=>"matt", :lastName=>"master", :gender => 1)
```

with no bang after the .create method. This should not generate an error. Now type:

```
test
```

It's very likely that you have required key values set as "nil" and that the object can't be saved from console until you fill in the appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually called www.railshotline.com and Chap helped me out.  I had created my own getter and setter methods for firstName.  They worked for everything but creating basically.  Removed them and wrote another method in its place without changing the getters/setters.  Bingo.